# Refactoring monsterous JavaScript-project

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I've found myself from the monstrous JavaScript-project. I haven't seen any references to known design patterns and code files consists of 5000+ rows of messy code. Usual length of the function is about 100 lines. Also namespaces are messy. Any ideas how to get any sense for this project?

I've been trying to read the source code, but there are no comments whatsoever. Also there are no tests, so making changes is a matter of luck.

Abandoning the project is not a choice.

Are there any nice tools for helping? At the moment I'm using sublime & Chrome.

Comment: Step through it with a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the specs you could write tests then refactor safely. Your tests will tell you if you break anything.

On the other hand if you don't have specs, you can write your tests by generating a bunch of random values and record the associated results. With your current code, you know (by definition) that they are correct.

I have seen the latter approach at a conference about refactoring ugly, legacy code. The speaker generated lots of random value/result pairs, turned them into unit tests, and started refactoring ultra-quickly. The results were quite amazing and you knew for sure that nothing had broken in the process.

Of course, if your application is more complex than the "give me an input, i'll tell you the output" style, this is trickier. But maybe it will get you started !

Comment: This sounds like a good approach. I've no specs and execution line is bouncing here and there. There are some frameworks mixed up, as well as a bunch of functions, so this will be an interesting challenge.

Comment: Are there any tools for mapping the source code according their execution paths. What I mean is that some tool, which allows me to see how some code travels trough the code. I know the debugger, but it's so slow to use at.